# e.keyCode doesn't work

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm new at programming and I do whatever I see in the youtube video to create a game with canvas. This code works in the video but doesn't work for me.I don't see key codes on the screen so key code thing doesn't work . I don't know what is wrong with  the coding..

My codes:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var keys[];
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  alert(e.keyCode);
}, false);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>GAME</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="mainCanvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Change `var keys[];` to `var keys = [];`

Comment: Check your javascript console for errors

Answer (score 1):

Always, when developing, do it with an open console. You're receiving the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`.

That's because you don't create arrays in JS like that. You actually do: `var arr = [];`. Just change `var keys[]` to `var keys = [];`

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/02f6nyh9/

javascript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var keys = new Array();
// var keys = []; // Either of these work
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  alert(e.keyCode);
}, false);

context.fillRect(0,0,500,400);
```

You just need to create an array correctly then it works fine :)

Comment: Thankss This site is awesome (:

Comment: @Didem if this is the correct answer please tick it :) or tick Yavor's answer

Comment: I don't have 15 reputation it seems sorry :o